Getting "Signature is invalid" error while integrating meeting sdk in Ionic Capacitor + Angular Project
I have created app using Ionic Capacitor + Angular and installed @zoom/meetingsdk package into it. I've created meeting sdk app in zoom marketplace. And I am using Zoom signature generation project for generating signature. Following is my frontend code:
import { Component, Inject, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';

import { ZoomMtg } from '@zoom/meetingsdk';

ZoomMtg.preLoadWasm();

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage {

  authEndpoint = 'http://localhost:4000'
  sdkKey = /SDK KEY OF MY APP/
  meetingNumber = /MEETING NUMBER OF MY SCHEDULED MEETING/
  passWord = /PASSWORD OF MEETING/
  role = 1
  userName = 'Shruti'
  userEmail = 'test@gmail.com'
  registrantToken = ''
  zakToken = ''
  leaveUrl = 'http://localhost:8100'

  constructor(public httpClient: HttpClient, private ngZone: NgZone) { }

  getSignature() {
    this.httpClient.post(this.authEndpoint, {
      meetingNumber: this.meetingNumber,
      role: this.role
    }).toPromise().then((data: any) => {
      if (data.signature) {
        console.log(data.signature)
        this.startMeeting(data.signature)
      } else {
        console.log(data)
      }
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log(error)
    })
  }

  startMeeting(signature: any) {

    let container = document.getElementById('zmmtg-root');
    if (container)
      container.style.display = 'block'

    this.ngZone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
      ZoomMtg.init({
        leaveUrl: this.leaveUrl,
        isSupportAV: true,
        patchJsMedia: true,
        leaveOnPageUnload: true,
        success: (success: any) => {
          console.log(success, "Init success");
          ZoomMtg.join({
            signature: signature,
            sdkKey: this.sdkKey,
            meetingNumber: this.meetingNumber,
            passWord: this.passWord,
            userName: this.userName,
            userEmail: this.userEmail,
            // tk: this.registrantToken,
            // zak: this.zakToken,
            success: (success: any) => {
              console.log(success, "Join success")
            },
            error: (error: any) => {
              console.log(error, "Join Error")
            }
          })
        },
        error: (error: any) => {
          console.log(error, "Init Error")
        }
      })
    })
  }
}

And getting below error in join method:
{
"method": "join",
"status": false,
"result": "Invalid signature.",
"errorCode": 3712,
"errorMessage": "Signature is invalid."
}

